# IOS distribution certificate is grayout

Tags: ios, app-store

My app is completed and now I want to distribute it in **App Store** but the iOS distribution option is grayed-out. If I delete the previous distribution certificate then is there any problem in my app which is on **App Store**?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no problem when you delete the previous ones. The right way to renew the old distribution certificate is 'Revoke'. This will not effect your other apps which are already in App Store.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem this. Distribution certificates expire anyway, so eventually it will happen that you need a new one. Go ahead and delete away.

Basically Revoking a certificate has no relation to the App Store or existing apps. Once you revoke your certificate, it will be deleted from the list of certificates.

Comment: But some app is on waiting for review , if i delete a certificate then provisioning profile will be invalid

Comment: So that you need to wait :-(

Comment: Nope there is no issue

Comment: @AbhishekPathak, Don't worry about the existing Waiting For Review OR In Review apps.. It won't get affected anyways.. Go ahead & revoke it out...

Answer (score 0):

No it will not create any problem... You can revoke the certificate any time even when your application is in **Waiting For Review/In Review** state.

According to Apple support, you can revoke the certificate immediately after submitting an app for review and the app won't be affected.

Answer (score -1):

For your information, you have gray-out option simply because you have reached the upper limit of distribution certificates you can create. For your question, you are safe to delete any distribution certificates.

Would suggest developers to look for official documentation instead.

Comment: He would like to know wether deleting the existing certificate will create issue or not?

Comment: Did you see that I include "FYI"? I just want to let him know that the reason why the option is grayed out.

Comment: Yes I seen that.. but he knows that thing I think & because of that he would like to revoke it otherwise no need to add question.. Hope you got my point..